# wierd behavior on Scrolling selenium

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, scroll, ui-automation

I'm working on ui automation and recently discovered one interesting behavior. 
Sometimes I need to scroll to some particular element and I've been using both, JS function to scroll to element and actions.moveToElement(WebElement)

This seem to work for any checkboxes, textboxes, buttons types of elements, but when i need to move to the table cell () of the table which has multiple columns - see that table is being shift to the left, this happens almost every time.  Let say there is a table 5x5 and i'm only looping over 5th column, when i do scroll2element via either of those 2 functions - the whole table is getting messed up. all the previous columns would disappear and my 5th column is shifting all the way to the left.

I found the workaround - instead of scrolling to specific table cell i scroll to the button that is located on top of that table, but just out of curiosity, if anyone experienced such an issue and what did they do? Thanks

Comment: The problem you've encountered could be due to any number of things. It could be a bug in the JavaScript of the page you are using (which you've worked around with your solution). It could be that you are not doing what you think you are doing with your Selenium script. It would be a timing issue (not waiting for the right event).

Comment: Generally, I set the window to maximize when I create an instance of the driver.  It seems to solve a lot of those sorts of scrolling issues.

Comment: ok, so my window is maximized, also when i'm scrolling to element, this element i find via wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElement(By..) So i'm highly sure it should have been ok, also even if i add some thread.sleep after driver finds element when i scroll to it i will see that problem. This is that js function:    WebElement x =wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(by));
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                "arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", x); 

action.moovetoelement does the same. Are you saying there r bugs in JS at my project?

Comment: @Gino It's just not possible to tell without seeing your script and the page you are trying to work on. Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you problem could be with selectors.

Try using CSS selectors over the XPath,  from my life experience XPath doesnt work as well ass CSS.

Also i'm always using JS and never had any problems.

try that

```
   WebElement x = driver.findElement(by);
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(
                "arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", x);
```